# Joined Report in Salesforce

Tags: reporting

I am new to reports in Salesforce esp joined reports. I have a user report with some filter and it has 100 in it. Now, I have to make report on Opp where Opp Owner is among in those 100 user in User report.

Can I do with joined reports. ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a joined report will help you here and I'm not even sure that you could do it with a joined report since a joined report does an outer-join.
Have a look at this question here which makes my point clear:
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000ghqoAAA

Normally, you should just be able to do the filter immediately on your opportunity report.
You should be able to filter on fields from the "opportunity owner" as well.

If you don't see the user fields you need there, create a new custom report type.
There, you can add the fields you need from your opportunity owner by choosing the "add fields from related objects".